# Log message transfer in RabbitMQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, rabbitmq

I have implemented RabbitMQ in .Net MVC successfully.Now i need to log each message transfer done  through my RabbitMQ server,is it possible.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test the logs for the messages going through Rabbitmq then you can enable the `rabbitmq_tracer` plugin in rabbitmq and it will log the messages for you. This plugin is good for testing as it shows detailed log for the messages.

Comment: Thanks.I tried rabbitmq_tracer plugin firehose and it is working.but i noticed some performance issue.Is there any solution to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to log failed message details then `RabbitMQ` already provide a log file with failed message transfer detailes.The Log file located at `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\log\rabbit@username.txt'